# tkinter Entry validatecommand cannot call Entry.config()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In Python 3.6.6, I would like to configure a tkinter Entry widget whenever another Entry widget is modified. Entry widgets don't have a callback function, but they do have validatecommand, which can work the same way if validate='focus'. However, the interpreter doesn't recognize the to-be-modified Entry widget within the validatecommand function. Here is my minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class app:
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.root = window

        self.tv1 = tk.DoubleVar(None,2)
        self.tv2 = tk.DoubleVar(None,3)
        self.tv3 = tk.DoubleVar(None,0)

        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.tv1,
                               validate='focus', validatecommand=self.valid)
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.tv2,
                               validate='focus', validatecommand=self.valid)
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.tv3)

        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.label1.pack()

    def valid(self):
        self.tv3.set(self.tv1.get()*self.tv2.get())
        self.label1.config(fg='red')
        return True

main = tk.Tk()
win = app(main)
main.mainloop()
```

which returns

> AttributeError: 'app' object has no attribute 'label1'

which is obviously not true.

Comment: Note that the script works if you remove `self.label1.config(fg='red')`, and properly multiplies the two numbers and updates the result Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validate command is being called for the first time before the label is created.

You can solve this by creating the label before creating the entry widgets.

Comment: Awesome! However, what if I have entries that need to modify each other? Is this just not possible using validatecommand?

Comment: @smp55: anything is possible. the bottom line is, you can't write code that tries to modify something that doesn't exist yet. You could create the entries without the `validatecommand` option, and then add that option after everything is created. Or, modify your command to check that they exist and do nothing if they don't.